# Override UILabel draw rect inside UIButton

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to override the UILabel "drawTextInRect" inside a UIButton, so I can create a border around the text.

I have my code that works perfectly with a UILabel

```
class LabelBorder: UILabel {

    override func drawTextInRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let shadowOffset = self.shadowOffset
        let textColor = self.textColor

        let c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextSetLineWidth(c, 1)
        CGContextSetLineJoin(c, kCGLineJoinRound)

        CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(c, kCGTextStroke)
        self.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        self.alpha = 0.35
        super.drawTextInRect(rect)

        CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(c, kCGTextFill)
        self.textColor = textColor
        self.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0)
        self.alpha = 1.0
        super.drawTextInRect(rect)

        self.shadowOffset = shadowOffset
    }

}
```

But I change a UILabel to a UIButton so I can detect easily the touch up inside action, but I still need the border around the text so I try to modify the code to this

```
class LabelBorderBtn: UIButton {


    // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
        super.drawRect(rect)


        let shadowOffset = self.titleLabel?.shadowOffset
        let textColor = self.titleLabel?.textColor

        let c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextSetLineWidth(c, 1)
        CGContextSetLineJoin(c, kCGLineJoinRound)

        CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(c, kCGTextStroke)
        self.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        self.titleLabel?.alpha = 0.35
        self.titleLabel?.drawTextInRect(rect)

        CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(c, kCGTextFill)
        self.titleLabel?.textColor = textColor
        self.titleLabel?.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0)
        self.titleLabel?.alpha = 1.0
        self.titleLabel?.drawTextInRect(rect)

        self.titleLabel?.shadowOffset = shadowOffset!
    }
}
```

This code didn't work and of course because the TitleLabel its drawing tree times, the default plus two in this code. But there is a way to subclass the UILabel inside the UIButton or any other idea to get border in that label?

I really don't want to detect tap gestures because this buttons are in a tableview with 8 different types of cells

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want your button to have a border you can try this

```
var button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50))
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
button.setTitle("Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
button.titleLabel?.layer.borderWidth = 1
button.titleLabel?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Marius, this work to get a border around the button, but I want a border around the text inside the button

Comment: Hi @MariusFanu, thanks, but that create a border around the bounds of the text I need a border on each letter like if you click on border text in PSD

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it, bases on the class I write LabelBorder that I post on the question. The solution is

```
class LabelBorderBtn: UIButton {


    // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
        super.drawRect(rect)

        if let oldLabel = self.titleLabel {
            let newLabel = LabelBorder(frame: oldLabel.frame)
            newLabel.text = oldLabel.text
            newLabel.font = oldLabel.font
            newLabel.textColor = oldLabel.textColor

            oldLabel.removeFromSuperview()
            self.addSubview(newLabel)
        }
}
```

I know it's not a fancy solution, but it works and also works with a UITableView